# vertical scroll bars events not raised in datagrid view

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, scrollbar

I have a datagrid view like this....in below image well thats works fine...

I need to hook up an event in vertical side bar ..

i mean if i click on upper arrow in the scroll bar i want to do something ...

To be more specific i want to get the id of first upper record id when i click on upper arrow in  vertical scroll bar..

```
 using System.Reflection;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

bool addScrollListener(DataGridView dgv)
{
   bool ret = false;

   Type t = dgv.GetType();
    PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty("VerticalScrollBar", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    ScrollBar s = null;

   if (pi != null)
    s = pi.GetValue(dgv, null) as ScrollBar;

   if (s != null)
  {
    s.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(s_Scroll);
    ret = true;
  }
  return ret;
}

private void s_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll)
    {
        if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.ThumbPosition)
        {
            if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.SmallIncrement)
            {

                int i = dgvMembers.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
                int idemebers =Convert.ToInt32(dgvMembers.Rows[i].Cells["Id"].Value.ToString());
                getMemberInfo(i, idemebers); // i want to the details of selected record into text boxes 

            }
            if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.SmallDecrement)
            {

                int i = dgvMembers.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
                int idemebers = Convert.ToInt32(dgvMembers.Rows[i].Cells["Id"].Value.ToString());
                getMemberInfo(i, idemebers);

            }
        }

    }   
}
```

but this event does not fire

```
s.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(s_Scroll);
```

it does not goes into the this event ...

would any one pls help on this...

Many thanks in advance

Comment: can't you use `dgv.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(s_Scroll)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [DataGridView.Scroll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.scroll.aspx) event.

> To be more specific i want to get the id of first upper record id when i click on upper arrow in vertical scroll bar

In your `DataGridView.Scroll` event handler, you can do this (the upper arrow is considered a small decrement:

```
if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll
    && e.Type == ScrollEventType.SmallDecrement)
{
    int i = dgvMembers.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
    // your code to process the first displayed row here
}
```